# How to define section from scratch

Tags: sectioning

I'm writing my own document class from scratch (as a learning exercise) and I'm stuck with defining my own sections.

I don't like `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` etc. convention and am more inclined towards markdown approach (e.g. `#` for level 1 title, `##` for level two etc...).

So I want to define my level 0 title as `\h`, my level 1 as `\hh` and so on.

If I use my definition of `\h` I get `undefined control sequence [\end{document}]`:

```
[Compiling C:\Users\mastarija\Desktop\LaTexIng\CurriculumVitae\CurriculumVitae.tex]

Basic Builder: running xelatex...done.

Errors:

C:\Users\mastarija\Desktop\LaTexIng\CurriculumVitae\CurriculumVitae.tex:9: Undefined control sequence. [\end{document}]

No warnings.

C:\Users\mastarija\Desktop\LaTexIng\CurriculumVitae\CurriculumVitae.log:1: Double-click here to open the full log.

[Done!]
```

Here's my test document:

```
\documentclass{CurriculumVitae}

\begin{document}

\h{Some title}

This is super duper

\end{document}
```

And here's my class file so far:

```
% METADATA

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CurriculumVitae}

% CORE SETUP

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% DEFAULT SETTINGS

% Layout

\geometry{top=4cm,left=4cm,right=4cm,bottom=4cm}

% Typography

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% Headings

\newcounter{h}
\newcommand{\h}{\@startsection{h}{0}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{\scshape}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only showed a scrambled form of the error message. Your log file will show

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...ct \numberline {1}Some title}{\thepage 
                                                  }\protected@file@percent }
l.9 \end{document}
```

Adding

```
\newcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
```

to your class file makes it work without error, or perhaps better copy the form used by `article` class:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

You will also need to define `\hmark` to supply code to add to the page head or discard the title eg

```
\newcommand\hmark[1]{}
```

is enough to prevent the text appearing twice.

Comment: It works now, thanks! Do you maybe know why my section is doubling the title now?

Comment: @Maštarija see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The doubling is caused by a `\@dblarg` call somewhere in the definition of the sectioning commands. You can force the command to use the starred version to avoid the doubling:

```
\newcounter{h}
\def\thepage{\relax}
\def\h{\hstar*}
\newcommand{\hstar}{\@startsection{h}{0}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{\scshape}}
```

[image]

However, you will likely encounter many more problems when trying to incorporate commands from standard classes in a new class that has different or missing definitions. The easiest way is most probably to just use `article` and combine that with `\def\h{\section}` commands etc. if you don't like the names.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just playing around so I'm not too worried about things being hard.